# How to split this complex string into 3 columns and 50 rows using Google sheet script

Tags: arrays, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i've searched for some time but did not quite find what i need.

I've got this string:

```
["384.23","0.01",1],["383.9","16.15406671",2],["383.26","8.62406671",1],
["383.25","0.01",1],["383.22","6.57026928",1],["383.21","0.20029",1],....
```

It has 50 of these triplets, each within brackets.

I would like to split this data into 3 columns and 50 rows. For example the first row would contain 384.23 in col1, then 0.01 in col2 and 1 in column 3.
Then on next row i would find the next triplet, and onto 50 rows like this.

I've tried to put this into an array, but i'm just going nowhere. Here's my code so far:

```
var array2 = [{}];

array2 = rawbids.split("],[");

//copy each element of array2 in a column
rgMyRange = first.getRange("B10:B59");

rgMyRange.setValue([array2])
```

but i only get this value in first column repeated on next 50 rows: `["384.23","0.01",1`

and my code above would not even split the triplets yet....

thanks a lot

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse()` in google spreadsheet, can't you?

Comment: `var array2 = JSON.parse('[' + rawbids + ']')`

Comment: thanks for the feed-back. My code is now:    //splitting each block of rawbids into an array
  //var array2 = [{}];
  var array2 = JSON.parse('[' + rawbids + ']')
  Logger.log(array2);
  
  //copy each element of array2 in 3 columns and rows
  rgMyRange = first.getRange("B10:D59");

  rgMyRange.setValues([array2])    but that gives me error: Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 50 (line 176, file "Code")

Comment: sorry for the messy post above, i don't know how to get the normal editor to split my code, i can only comment.

Comment: `setValues(array2)`

Answer (score 0):

ok it's working now, thanks to the guys above:

```
  var array2 = JSON.parse('[' + rawbids + ']')

  //copy each element of array2 in 3 columns and rows
  rgMyRange = first.getRange("B10:D59");

  rgMyRange.setValues(array2)
```